Sound credits - AI dialogue treatment
How would you recommend to credit a dialogue editor using AI to manipulate the dialogues? As this is a sensitive topic, we'd like to explore ways to properly credit the editor who's generating fragments of the corrected dialogue which has been agreed by producers and talents as well.

Is any of it really "AI" though? Everyone calls it AI like it's an android doing your work for you, but in reality it's just machine learning. Feed it enough info, and it will put out the result you want.

Sound editing.  The toolset doesn't matter.

The credit would be Dialogue Editor. Audio production tools already contain AI for analysis and generation. Dialogue editors have been using AI tools in production, with or  without knowing it. Adobe Premiere Pro includes "Adobe Advanced Speech" which originated in Adobe Podcast. Other AI tools include Audio Category Tagging. This is Adobe's description (from Adobe Research):

...cleaning up sound samples [involves] removing background noise and
reverberation and balancing the sound. “With the old tools, getting a
good result from this process required a very deep level of expertise
in applying audio filters and chaining different audio operations
together...” explains Justin Salamon, Senior Research Scientist for
Adobe Research. But with Enhance Speech (a feature users can find on
the Essential Sound Panel), a single click produces audio that sounds
as clear as if it were recorded in a studio.

It is expected that audio editors will use state of the art tools. Existing editing software has AI built into its workflow. Generative AI  s becoming an important tool category in visual, video, and audio production. The details of how those tools work are not important, the result is what matters.

This doesn't answer the question, which is how to credit the dialog editor. Please edit your post to answer the question.
